# printf changing value of char*

Tags: c, string, printf

This is the part of my code where this is happening... whatever I am printing with the help of printf its output is repeating 3 times and that value is getting in path variable

```
char *path;
    char buf[1024];
    struct group grp;
    struct group *grpt;
    path=strdup(pointer);
    while((sd=readdir(dp))!=NULL)
    {   if(sd->d_name[0]=='.')
            continue;
        strcat(path,"/");
        strcat(path,sd->d_name);
        stat(path, &my_stat);
        printf("%s  \t ",sd->d_name);
        printf("\n");
        int x= (int) (strlen(path) - strlen(sd->d_name));
        path[x-1]='\0';
        path;
    }
```

Comment: `path=strdup(pointer); [...] strcat(path,"/");` <- stop right here. Whatever you get from `strdup()` doesn't have space to append something.

Comment: You need to manage your storage precisely.  `path` is allocated by `strdup`, and you must assume it contains only enough storage for the string that was copied (and the terminating null byte).  You cannot reuse it for something else unless you know it is large enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path=strdup(pointer);
...
strcat(path,"/");
```

This will cause *undefined behavior*. When `strdup` is invoked, it will return a pointer to an chunk of memory big enough to hold a copy of the string. It may be bigger, but there's no guarantee. When you're invoking `strcat` you are writing to unallocated memory.

One way to get around this is to manually specify how big path should be with a "big enough for all purposes" value. Something like this:

```
char path[1000];
strcpy(path, pointer);
```

If you want a more refined (not necessarily better) solution, you can use `realloc` to change the size of the allocated memory.

Comment: `s/1000/\`PATH_MAX\` from \`<limits.h>\`/`

Comment: how to use this PATH_MAX?

Comment: Are you familiar with `INT_MAX`?

Comment: `PATH_MAX` is the size including null terminator of the largest supported filename. It is a limitation. You could *try* to go beyond it, but don't expect things to go so well. *"How to use it?"* Like any other integer constant, I suppose? Sensibly... klutt, I'd like to suggest varying your example to `char path[PATH_MAX]; snprintf(path, sizeof path, "%s/%s", pointer, sd->d_name);` (across two lines, of course). OP appears to want to throw an entire directory listing into memory; so perhaps to store `n` paths:  `typedef char path[PATH_MAX]; path *p = malloc(n * sizeof *p);`...